# php mysql is this correct?

Tags: php, mysql

Is this Query and display info all correct? Syntax-wise.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("DATABASENAME?!?!") or die(mysql_error());
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME";
$result = mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['COLUMNNAME'] . "<br />";

}
mysql_close()
?>
```

Comment: No it isn't, because you should not be using `mysql_query()` anymore. Instead, use `mysqli_query()` or `PDO::query()`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: seems legit. What's the problem !?

Comment: It looks correct to me (I don't have anything available to check it with beyond my eyes, however).  Is it throwing an error?  If so, can you ammend your post to include it?

Comment: OP, check out RedBean. You'll thank me later. http://redbeanphp.com/

Comment: Probably not seen as though your asking people here :D

Comment: why those `?` and `!` in database name? just asking....

Comment: Thanks for the responses, lc, when you say use mysqli_query, you are just talking about the query correct?'

Comment: No the function. The function `mysql_*` is deprecated. About your code, it is perfectly fine. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use statement as

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD") or die (mysqli_error ());
mysqli_select_db("DATABASENAME",$conn) or die(mysqli_error());
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME";
$result = mysqli_query($strSQL) or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['COLUMNNAME'] . "<br />";

}
mysqli_close()
?>
```

Also I advice you to use Mysqli or Pdo instead of Mysql driver as it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your question or code. Syntax wise it is fine. But it is advised not to use `mysql_*` functions because it is deprecated.

The general way of using the code for your condition would be:

```
<?php
    mysqli_connect("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD") or die (mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db("DATABASENAME") or die(mysqli_error());
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME";
    $result = mysqli_query($strSQL) or die(mysqli_error());
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        foreach ($row as $column => $value)
            echo $column . " = " . $value . "<br />";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    mysqli_close();
?>
```

So, this iterates and suppose say you have four columns, and two rows, it gives an output like:

```
Column 1 Name = Value
Column 2 Name = Value
Column 3 Name = Value
Column 4 Name = Value

Column 1 Name = Value
Column 2 Name = Value
Column 3 Name = Value
Column 4 Name = Value
```

Comment: More of a better option is PDO.

Comment: if there are better, convenient option available, atleast mention it. None the less, above code is wrong. you are using `mysqli` yet for retrieval errors, you are using `mysql_error`.